# Imagem na menubar do PrimeFaces

Tags: java, css, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Olá, estou com um problema que consiste em não conseguir colocar um ícone a esquerda do menubar e os itens de menu a direita, alguém pode me ajudar?

```html
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:menubar>

            <f:facet name="options" >
                <h:link outcome="index.xhmtl">
                    <p:graphicImage styleClass="a" name="img/logoGovernoTO.png"/>
                </h:link>
            </f:facet>


            <p:menuitem value="NOTÍCIA" url="#"/>
            <p:menuitem value="FÓRUM" url="#"/>
            <p:menuitem value="EXPLORE" url="#"/>
            <p:menuitem value="SOBRE" url="#"/>
            <p:menuitem value="CONTATO" url="#"/>

        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

teria que ficar assim
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adicione isso na sua folha de estilo (estilo.css por exemplo)

```
.ui-menubar .ui-menubar-options {
    float: left !important;
}
.ui-menuitem {
    float: right !important
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!